# xampp curl Could not resolve host

Tags: php, curl, xampp, host, resolve

I host an application via xampp on a windows machine.
I created a custom url. Edited it in windows host file and xampp httpd-vhosts.conf
The application is running.

But when i try to make a curl call on an url, i get the error Could not resolve host: test.localhost

what am i doing wrong?

Here is my call:

```
$url = 'test.localhost/api_call';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
// curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
```

and here is the setting in httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *>
  # Pfad muss angepasst werden
  DocumentRoot C:\xampp\htdocs/sites
  ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
  # Pfad verweist auf Projekt-Ordner
  DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs/sites/test"
  ServerName test.localhost
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs/sites/test">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Have you edited `hosts` with administrator privileges?

Comment: yes i edited and saved it. Also changed it in the chosts file in xampp